# My ajax call returns a data with html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I saw  some posts with this question, but I still have the problem. When I make my ajax call, it returns the data that I expect, but with the HTML code of the whole page. I tried to put `dataType : 'Jason'` and many other things, but they don't help me.

```
function validarUsuario()
    {

        var Pseudo = $('#Pseudo').val();

          $.ajax({
            url:'Bienvenu.php',
            method:"POST",
            data:{'Pseudo':Pseudo},

             success:function(data)
             {  


              console.log('|' + data + '|')

              if(data != '0')
                {

                alert('pseudo already taken');

                }else 
                {
                    alert('pseudo correct');

                }

             }
            });





        }
```

///Bienvenu.php/////

```
        if(!$stmt->execute())
        {
            $sBody .= 'erreur<br />';
        }
        else
        {
            $iNbResultat = $stmt->rowCount();
            echo $iNbResultat;            




        }
```

///OUTPUT Firefox///  This is the data when I use console.log(data)

```
|<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>



 <body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1   /jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"> </script>

 0</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: What does Bienvenu.php look like?

Comment: Looks like you’re getting the response from the page you requested, plus some layout

Comment: This looks like there’s a problem in your server side code. The frontend (AJAX) does what it should.

Comment: How can i see if there a problem on the server side code ? @muka.gergely

Comment: Yes. It is probably the server side, the php file.  I would make a little HTML form to check out the response.

Comment: @lokoCoco you see it, because the result is not what you expect - that’s an error. The server generates the result, so it’s a server side error. Without server side code it cannot be debugged.

Comment: We would have to see all of Bienvenu.php